# UPDATE and DELETE Operation in Python Django REST

Tags: python, django, rest, crud

I am trying to implement simple CRUD operation in Django Rest. I have successfully created, `GET` and `POST` . Now, I want to update the row data with `PUT` and delete a row with `DELETE`.

Currently, my table looks like :-

```
id    item_1    item_2    item_3    date_created    date_modified

1     test1     test2     test3     16-12-2017      16-12-2017
2     ex1       ex2       ex3       16-12-2017      16-12-2017
```

API End point :- `localhost/itemlist`

If we `GET localhost/itemlist` it returns the list of items.

If we `POST localhost/itemlist` with fields `item_1`, `item_2`, `item_3` , it creates the row.

Now, I want to use `PUT` to update a particular row. Like, if I want to update the value of `item_3` where `item_1 == "test1"`

DELETE should delete the row where `item_1 == ex1`

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from .views import ItemView

urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^itemlists/$', ItemView.as_view(), name="create"),       
}

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

views.py :

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .serializers import itemlistSerializer
from .models import itemlist   

class ItemView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = itemlist.objects.all()
    serializer_class = itemlistSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):  
        serializer.save()
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import itemlist

class itemlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        """Meta class to map serializer's fields with the model fields."""
        model = itemlist
        fields = ('id', 'item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3', 'date_created', 'date_modified')
        read_only_fields = ('date_created', 'date_modified')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class itemlist(models.Model):
    """This class represents the itemlist model."""
    item_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    item_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)
    item_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=False)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a human readable representation of the model instance."""
        return "{}".format(self.item_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use django viewsets:

viewsets.py

```
class ListItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = itemlistSerializer
    queryset = itemlist.objects.all()
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'option']

    def get_queryset(self):
        request_user = self.request.user
        if not request_user.is_superuser:
            return self.queryset.filter(owner=request_user)
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(listitem', ListItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

Then you should be able to send put and delete requests. This works for Django 1.9x.

Just one more thing: Please read the [Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names). We normally use CamelCase for class names.

Comment: Good answer but you don't need to define the http_method_names. Also there's a mistake in the get_query_set method with request.user, it should be self.request.user

Comment: Thanks for that error. You are also right about http_method_names, but I think it's good to set the methods explicit. Sometimes you only need to allow get requests and so you can disable the other methods.